# $L:K$ is algebraic implies that $\bar{L}=\bar{K}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This is a question from Garling's book "A Course in Galois Theory":

Suppose that $L:K$ is algebraic. In what sense is it true that $\bar{L}=\bar{K}$? (the algebraic closure of $L$ is equal to the algebraic closure of $K$)

I think it is always true and here is my proof:

We want to prove that $\bar{L}=\bar{K}$, which means:

(a) $\bar{L}$ should be algebraic over $K$

(b) $\bar{L}$ splits all the irreducible polynomials $f(x)$ in $K[x]$

To prove (a): Since $\bar{L}$ is algebraic over $L$, and ${L}$ is algebraic over $K$, thus $\bar{L}$ should be algebraic over $K$.

To prove (b): Since $\bar{L}$ splits all the irreducible polynomials $f(x)$ in $L[x]$ and $K[x]\subset L[x]$, thus $\bar{L}$ splits all the irreducible polynomials $f(x)$ in $K[x]$.

(a) (b) are all satisfied, so the fact that $\bar{L}=\bar{K}$ is always true.

Comment: Yes, this is alright.

Comment: @MooS thanks for commenting!

Comment: Note that since the question asks "in what sense", it might be looking for a more precise answer. Namely, those fields need not be equal as sets (things rarely do). Instead, they will be isomorphic, and I suppose the question might be asking how "strong" an isomorphism one will have (i.e. one that is the identity on $K$? One that is the identity on $L$?).